# Create and store database locally with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a small website with couple different forms inserting data to sql. But the users have problem with it. The problem is that they seem to be going through them too fast that its not recording everything.
So i am trying to see if there was a way to store all the data locally and have it insert to sql at the end when they are done filling out forms. Is this possible?

For example:

I have a form that have 5 fields but 2 are auto populated and 1 entered manually and 2 are being inserted using bar code scanner. The bar code scanner is the last value required before being inserted, so i was hoping there was a way to insert that into locally store access database (not seen by anyone) and when they press "Finish" all that data from access will be inserted into sql.

Hope i painted the picture clear enough.

Let me know any and all possibilities.

EDIT: Here is the [aspx](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2653343/scan.txt) and [.cs](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2653343/scan_cs.txt), hope this helps. Yes i realize that i have validation for the bar code, but not sure why its slow. And i may have stuff cluttered. So please bear with me.

Comment: Your question should be "Why isn't my database saving all my data." They aren't going through them too fast, your code just has some problems. Please post some relevant parts so we can help identifying what is wrong.

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: Added link to the code.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to put that data in application session or cache and then flush the data to db.

Here are some other choices though:

- Flat files (simply serialize your objects, use protobuf)
- **Use Embeded Db: SqlLite, VistaDb, Sql Server Compact...**
- Store data in the browser via localstorage (dom storage, this is html 5 feature)

Comment: Well, I suppose it is not very clear from the question.But those concepts are good to know from the context of the question, and I doubt the answer is wrong. Since you can use application cache to quickly gather data, and flush it later to DB....

Comment: If his code isn't properly saving data to his DB, why would it start working if the source is localstorage instead of a form post? There is no reason why he can't make his DB inserts work.

Comment: Sounds like that would be the first problem to tackle, if there is a DB issue. The ask seem to be for a temporary storage. It answers that question. However, if it doesn't help the questioner, I will delete the answer.